# Можно ли сделать вывод PDF файла в формате BASE 64 без верхнего встроенного меню?

Tags: html, pdf

Можно ли сделать вывод **PDF** файла в формате **BASE 64** без верхнего встроенного меню?

То есть убрать вот это:

[image: меню]

Comment: html не поддерживает pdf. это меню поставляется плагином. Боюсь что нет.

Comment: Можно рискнуть - попробовать в iframe обрезать.

Comment: @nick_n_a , а pdf base 64 строку в iframe засунуть можно?

Comment: Да, поддерживает, кроме майкрософта ie. Только ie тоже ссылку в base64 не видит ни как pdf ни другое. Вот embed (не проверял) и object не поймут base64, а iframe и frame/frameset поддерживают src в формате браузера.

Comment: embed понимает base 64

Answer (score 1):

Можно, посредством [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), однако с Base64 может возникнуть проблема, функция для конвертации [тут](https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746).